# Return structure from Delphi in c#

Tags: c#, delphi, dllimport

I have a function written in Delphi (dll) that return a structure. This must be use by DllImport.

```
TSettings = record
   Error       : integer;
   NumOfAngles : integer;
   Angles      : array[1..21] of integer;
   Version : integer;
end;
```

and function

```
function GetSettings:TSettings; stdcall;
```

c# code:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Settings
{
  int Error;
  int NumOfAngles;
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 21)]
  int[] Angles = new int[21];
  int Version;

  public Laser_Settings()
  {
     Error = 0;
     NumOfAngles = 0;
     Version = 0;
  }
}

[DllImport("xxx.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern Settings GetSettings();
```

which called with

```
var settings = DelphiWrapper.GetSettings();
```

I become this Exception:

```
MarshalDirectiveException- Method's type signature is not PInvoke compatible
```

What is wrong in my marshaling? I use VS 2022 with .NET Framework 4.7.2.

Thank you.

Comment: In Delphi this function is implemented as a procedure which takes the return value as a var parameter. So do the same in C#. Convert it to a void function and with a ref param of type `ettings` although I think that's a typo. You definitely should not be writing code in questions, you should paste it directly from your source so that there can't be transcription mistakes.

Comment: The sizes are wrong too. The Delphi array has 20 items, the C# field has 22 (arrays are 0-based in most languages) but the ` SizeConst` parameter is 21

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos His Delphi array `TSettings.Angles` has 21 elements, numbered from 1 to 21.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That's right, except that the delphi array has 21 items

Comment: Duuh. Haven't worked with Pascal or Delphi for over 20 years and the switch from 0- to 1-based indexing still confuses me at first. I hope I never get comfortable with it again :P

Comment: I cannot test it, no Delphi, but I think you cannot return a `struct` like this.  Can you try declaring Settings as `class` for the interop?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: thank you very mach, it's funkt's.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Pascal static arrays can start on any number you want, not only 1!

Comment: @DelphiCoder so happy I forgot this. Even though Pascal was the very first language I learned at Uni.